# Many to Many field and Nested Serializer in REST: Overwriting Nested serializer doesn't create nested object in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models with a many to many relation and 
I am trying to send nested data to my API. Unfortunately it only gives me back an empty array.

This is what I am trying:

my models:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    net_leased_area = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    description           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    buildings             = models.ManyToManyField(Building, default=None, blank=True)
```

My generic API view:

```
class BuildingGroupCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset                    = BuildingGroup.objects.all()
    serializer_class            = BuildingGroupSerializer
```

My serializer:

```
class BuildingGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    buildings = BuildingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:

        model = BuildingGroup

        fields = (
            'description',
            'buildings',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        buildings_data = validated_data.pop('buildings')
        building_group = BuildingGroup.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for building_data in buildings_data:
            Building.objects.create(building_group=building_group, **building_data)
        return building_group
```

When I send data it returns this:

```
{"description":"Test Description API","buildings":[]}
```

In the array I would like to have my array of dictionaries.

I am trying to follow the REST documentation here when I am overwriting the create method to send a nested object. (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) and I thought I am doing this correctly, but epic fail.

I send data with request with my custom method like this:

```
test_api_local(method="post", data={
        "description": "Test Description API",
        "buildings": [{'name' : 'Testname'}, .... ],
         })
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks so much!!

EDIT: When I try to test it on the REST view it tells me:

`TypeError: 'building_group' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

EDIT2: Here is my view:

```
class BuildingGroupCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset                    = BuildingGroup.objects.all()
    serializer_class            = BuildingGroupSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = BuildingGroupSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: no ideas anyone?

Comment: First of all, you should use, `get_or_create()` for `Building` inside the `create()` or `update()` of serializer.

Comment: Thank you Akshay. I changed my line to this ```building_group = BuildingGroup.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)``` This throws me the following error: ```building_data.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one BuildingGroup - it returned 7!``` Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: is it because of my many to many relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly get or create the `Building` instances, depending upon passed id's inside the payload data, then add them to `BuildingGroup` instance.

```py
class NestedBuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = '__all__'


class BuildingGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    buildings = NestedBuildingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BuildingGroup
        fields = (
            'description',
            'buildings',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        buildings_data = validated_data.pop('buildings')
        building_group = BuildingGroup.objects.create(**validated_data)
        buildings = []  # it will contains list of Building model instance
        for building_data in buildings_data:
            building_id = building_data.pop('id', None)
            building, _ = Building.objects.get_or_create(id=building_id,
                                                         defaults=building_data)
            buildings.append(building)
        # add all passed instances of Building model to BuildingGroup instance
        building_group.buildings.add(*buildings)
        return building_group

class BuildingGroupView(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    queryset = BuildingGroup.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuildingGroupSerializer


## Assume you add your views like this in urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    .....
    path('building-groups', views.BuildingGroupView.as_view(),
         name='building-group'),
    .....
]
```

On calling endpoint `/building-groups` as **POST** method with payload like this:

```
{
  "description": "here description",
  "buildings": [
    {
      "id": 1, # existing building of id 1
      "name": "name of building 1",
      "net_leased_area": 1800
    },
    { 
      # a new building will gets create
      "name": "name of building 2",
      "net_leased_area": 1800
    }
  ]
}
```

Then , it will return response like this:-

```
{
  "description": "here description",
  "buildings": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name of building 1",
      "net_leased_area": 1800
    },
    {
      "id": 2
      "name": "name of building 2",
      "net_leased_area": 1800
    }
  ]
}
```

Learn about [M2M relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)
and, [`.get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

> Note: `BuildingSerializer` and `NestedBuildingSerializer` are both different. Don't mix them up.

Comment: Thank you so much Akshay!! I will definitely read up on the topics. Your code though gives me the following: ```AssertionError: `create()` did not return an object instance.``` I did change this line like that:                                               ```buildings.append(Building.objects.get_or_create(id=building_id, defaults={'defaults': buildings_data[0]}))``` because it threw me a syntax error. But also like this I get the Assertion Error. Could you help me out again or point me into the right direction? thanks again

Comment: @Micromegas I have updated the answer, please look into it again.

Comment: Akshay, thank you so so much for your help and time. That's fantastic! Another question: In my view, this line: ```serializer = BuildingGroupSerializer(data=data)``` What is data referring to? Cause I get an unresolved reference for data and I don't understand what you are passing as argument there.

Comment: Here `data` can be payload you get in request, so you can do like `serializer = BuildingGroupSerializer(data=request.data)`

Comment: ah ok I understand. I am still getting an empty list for my buildings.... I am using a generic view though like: ```class BuildingGroupCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView)```. So I tried to overwrite the perform_create method like ```def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer = BuildingGroupSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()```  Was that what you meant? Because unfortunately I am still getting this empty list for buildings

Comment: Maybe I am overwriting it wrong? Because the response that you are describing is exactly what I need

Comment: You don't have to overwrite the `create` method of `CreateAPIView`, because what you are doing in `BuildingGroupCreateAPIView`, it's same things what `CreateAPIView` provides by default to you on `post()` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195845/discussion-between-akshay-pratap-singh-and-micromegas).

Comment: This solution works like a charm! Many thanks to you Akshay, you really helped me out alot!!